# Add shell script as executable to catkin package to use with rosrun

Tags: c++, shell, cmake, ros, catkin

When using a catkin package it is possible to start the c++ executables, that were added in the `CMakeLists.txt`, using the command `rosrun <package_name> <executable_name>` from anywhere on the computer.

Is there a way to add a shell script as an executable to the catkin package so that it can be called using `rosrun <package_name> <script.sh>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. You can do this by performing the following steps:

You need to place your script in the *scripts* folder of your package. Also the script needs to be marked as executable (`chmod +x your_script.sh`).

After sourcing your workspace, you can run and launch the script with ROS tools like

```
rosrun your_package your_script.sh
```

Note that you need to add your script also to the *CMakeLists.txt* in case of installation:

```
install(PROGRAMS scripts/your_script.sh
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```